# How to deploy WPF to cloud to easy download and update it by customer

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment, cloud, release

I wrote open-source WPF application whose source code is available via GitHub.

I use ClickOnce in visual studio to publish it to local directory.

My goal is to create just a link for user who will download the self-contained .exe app, it should automatically check for updates when I publish new version.

Can you give me an advice how to put the app to cloud so user can easily download it via a link and where to put it? (Great if it is free or cheap)
I read about GitHub Pages and Azure Blob Storage, can it be right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub Pages and Azure Blob Storage are both good options for hosting your self-contained .exe app.

GitHub Pages

GitHub Pages is a static site hosting service that is built into GitHub. It is free to use for public repositories, and private repositories can be hosted for free with GitHub Actions.

To host your app on GitHub Pages, you will need to create a separate repository for your app's assets. This repository should contain the following files:

Your self-contained .exe app
A `_config.yml` file that tells GitHub Pages how to serve your app
An index.html file that contains a link to your app
Once you have created the repository, you can publish your app to GitHub Pages by pushing your changes to the repository.

Azure Blob Storage

Azure Blob Storage is a cloud storage service that offers a variety of storage options, including object storage, block storage, and file storage. It is relatively inexpensive, and it offers a variety of features, such as static site hosting and integration with other Azure services.

To host your app on Azure Blob Storage, you will need to create a storage account and a container. Once you have created the container, you can upload your self-contained .exe app to the container.

To make your app available for download, you can create a public access policy for the container. This will allow anyone to access the app without having to authenticate.

Creating a link for users to download the app

Once you have hosted your app in the cloud, you can create a link for users to download it. The link should point to the self-contained .exe app.

If you are using GitHub Pages, the link will be in the following format:

```
https://<username>.github.io/<repository>/<app.exe>
```

If you are using Azure Blob Storage, the link will be in the following format:

```
https://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<app.exe>
```

Automatically checking for updates

You can use a variety of tools and techniques to automatically check for updates to your app. One option is to use a tool such as Squirrel. Squirrel is a free and open-source framework that can be used to create self-updating desktop apps.

To use Squirrel, you will need to add the Squirrel library to your app and make some changes to your app's code. Once you have done this, you can build and publish your app as usual.

When a user launches your app, Squirrel will check for updates. If an update is available, Squirrel will download and install the update automatically.

Conclusion

GitHub Pages and Azure Blob Storage are both good options for hosting your self-contained .exe app. GitHub Pages is a good option if you are looking for a free and easy-to-use solution. Azure Blob Storage is a good option if you need more features or if you are already using other Azure services.

Once you have hosted your app in the cloud, you can create a link for users to download it. You can also use a tool such as Squirrel to automatically check for updates to your app.

Comment: Was the content in this post generated by _ChatGPT_?